# How to check Sqlite if record exist in c# android

Tags: c#, android, sqlite

I have c# android application. I have a form with some fields jobno, route, cost and when user fill the form and press save, the information gets stored in SQLite database in app.

What I would like to do is add an if statement to if check if the record exist; add an entry if not don't add a record.

This is my code when user click save button.

```
    Record photo = new Record()
    {
        Jobno = jobno.Text,
        route= route.Text,
        cost= cost.Text,
        Timestamp = timestamp.Timestamp,

    };



    using (SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
    {

        //check if records exist


        conn.CreateTable<Record>();
        var numberofrows = conn.Insert(record);

        if (numberofrows > 0)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Success", "record has been saved successfully", "Ok");
            MainImage.Source = " ";
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayAlert("Failure", "Error occoured while saving record", "Try again");
        }
    }
```

How to add if statement to only add a new record if don't exist.

Thanks in advance

### Edit question

```
    using (SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
    {

        //check if records exist


        conn.CreateTable<Record>();
        var items = conn.Table<Record>().Where(array => array.Jobno == photo.Jobno && array.Applicationletter == photo.Applicationletter && array.Signno == photo.Signno);

        if (items == null)
        {
            var numberofrows = conn.Insert(photo);

            if (numberofrows > 0)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Success", "record has been saved successfully", "Ok");
                MainImage.Source = " ";
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("Failure", "Error occoured while saving record", "Try again");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayAlert("Failure", "Photo already exist", "ok");
        }

        //clear the notes field
        notesentry.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: To see if a record exists, you should query a select statement with the required fields and see whether the database returns a result. If it doesn't, the record does not exist yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this method. I'm not sure how your sqlite code works so im just guessing here. I am also guessing that you want to check if the newly created record exist, so this code is based off that.

```
conn.CreateTable<Record>();
//check if records exist
var items = conn.Table<Record>().Where(array => array.Jobno == photo.Jobno && array.Applicationletter == photo.Applicationletter && array.Signno == photo.Signno);
if (items?.Count() == 0)
{
   var numberofrows = conn.Insert(record);

   if (numberofrows > 0)
   {
      DisplayAlert("Success", "record has been saved successfully", "Ok");
      MainImage.Source = " ";
   }
   else
   {
      DisplayAlert("Failure", "Error occoured while saving record", "Try again");
   }
}
else
{
       DisplayAlert("Failure", "Photo already exist", "ok");
}

        //clear the notes field
        notesentry.Text = "";
```

Comment: I just tried and get error "sqlite connection does not contain defination for select and no extenson method select". Any idea?

Comment: Im not sure what the method is named that your sqlite uses to get data from the database, if you know the name, use that instead of "Select". Or I can probably figure it out if you tell me the  namespace or nuget package you are using to call the sqilte.

Comment: I am using sqlite-net-pcl (1.5.231)

Comment: ok try: var items = conn.Get<Record>(r => r.Jobno == photo.Jobno && r.route == photo.route && r.cost == photo.cost && r.Timestamp == photo.Timestamp);

Comment: actually try this instead:  item = conn.Table<Record>().Where(r => r.Jobno == photo.Jobno && r.route == photo.route && r.cost == photo.cost && r.Timestamp == photo.Timestamp);

Comment: Thanks @jessie. I'm getting closer. When I create a new record; it fails to add a new record. It shows message records already exist.

Comment: Does it gives you that message when you call the insert, or does it give you that message when you create the table?

Comment: I believe the same button calls create and insert button function. I have updated code in the original question under the heading 'Edit Question'

Comment: ok here is a minor change: change `if (items == null)` to `if (items?.Count() == 0 )`